# Specman e: simultaneous events error

Tags: specman, e

in my environment I have a signal that must not change between 2 time points. To verify it, I use `expect` rule:

```
my_signal : uint; 
event first_e; -- First time point
event second_e; -- Second time point
expect @first_e => {[0..]*(not {change(my_signal)}); @second_e} @clock;
```

The problem is that `@second_e` and `change(my_signal)` occurs on the same cycle (and it is OK) but the `expect` rule fails.

Do you have an idea how can to resolve it?
Maybe there is some way to specify event order or to tell that on the same cycle occurrence is OK?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sequence does not specify that same cycle is OK.

try this:

```
event my_sig_change is change(my_signal)@clock;
expect @first_e => {[0..]* not @my_sig_change; @second_e or (@second_e and @my_sig_change) } @clock;
```